# How do I check if I have a data that fits a parameter through a macro

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to check if I have a data that fits the month and year the user inputed my macro so I could know to which query to go, how do I do that?
my code so far:

```vba
Sub macro1()
    Dim year As Integer
    Dim month As Integer
    year = InputBox("What year would you want to get data from?")
    month = InputBox("What month would you want to get data from")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *DLookup*:

```
Dim DataExists As Boolean

If Not IsNull(DLookup("[SomeField]", "[YourTable]", "DateDiff('m', [YourDateField], DateSerial(" & year & ", " & month & ", 1)) = 0") Then
    DataExists = True
End If
```